# Calculating the front vector and look at vector

Tags: opencv, opengl, vector, glulookat

I have got a homogeneous matrix of shape 4x4. How do I retrieve the front vector and the look at vector from the homogeneous matrix?

Following is my homogeneous matrix,

```
pose = np.array([ 0.23522,-7.0289e-17,-0.97194,-129.54,
0.97194,-7.3988e-17,0.23522,59.464,
-8.8446e-17,-1,5.0913e-17,2.11,
0,0,0,1]).reshape(4,4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot post any comments yet, I'll post this as an answer.
Take a look at [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) tutorial. Is this what you need?